# JasperReports: JRPdfExporter causing OOME Java heap spac

Tags: java, jasper-reports, heap-memory, java-ee-7

I am using JRSwapFileVirtualizer for large datasets from the Oracle database, reports are filled by SQL query.
JasperFillManager.fillReport ends successfully, jasperPrint is created and JRSwapFileVirtualizer is used properly.

In the report design, I have got a table dataset, with 8 grouping criteria. When It comes to generating report PDF, I have got a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space:

```
      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append_i(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.formatDouble(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setLineCap(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.preparePen(JRPdfExporter.java:3147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportBottomPen(JRPdfExporter.java:3038)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportBox(JRPdfExporter.java:2891)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:3386)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:3379)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1063)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:927)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:547)
```

Points from my investigation:

- XLS export works just fine
- When I remove all the grouping + sum variables, PDF works fine and all 3900 pages are printed
- When I increase JVM memory, the report is generated but pdf is still corrupted and only first page works without lags

I have found a few similar issues on the internet, but not the solution.

Anyone can help me, please?

Kind regards,

Jan